# Как привязать значение из C# в XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Возник такой вопрос: есть данный код

```
<Image 
            Source="/Assets/New/arrow.png"
            Stretch="Fill" 
            x:Name="Ic_Arrow"
            Height="140" Width="14" 
            StretchDirection="Both" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,96,0,0" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.955">



            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-57.5"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>

            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter" >
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                From="-57.5" To="**?????**" 
                                Duration="0:0:.4">
                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                    <QuarticEase />
                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>


        </Image>
```

Могу ли я вместо вопросов в "To = ... " Привязать значение, рассчитываемое в C#? Например:

```
double RotateValue = 1 / (Math.Pow(Math.E, x.IndexOf(1) - 3) + 1);
```

И соответственно сделать некое такое:

```
From="-57.5" To="{Binding {RotateValue}"
```

Comment: Определенно можете, но синтаксис который вы используете немного неправильный. Напишите `To="{Binding RotateValue}"`. Вы добавили лишнюю `{`

Comment: @Aarnihauta исправил, все равно не изменяет поворот

Comment: В XAML вы не можете делать вычисления. Чтоб их сделать, придумали конверторы и расширения разметки. Вот в эту сторону и идите. Сделайте конвертор, в нем напишите эту формулу и привязывайте. А вообще, если вы привязываете это, то наверно за данные вычисление ответственно само `RotateValue`? Почему бы не написать в его `SET` эту логику?